# Getting the action's payload typing from within the effects

Tags: angular, ngrx

Sometimes you want your effect to take a value from the first action it subscribes to use it to the higher-order observable. The problem is that you don't have typings for those actions payload.

for example, I have a getWeather action that contains the cityId and asks the weather at the city from an API. These are the actions:

```
export const getWeather = createAction(
  '[Weather Api] Get Weather',
  props<{ cityId: number }>()
);

export const getWeatherSuccess = createAction(
  '[Weather Api] Get Weather Success',
  props<{ weather: IWeather }>()
);
```

And this is the effect that needs to use the cityId for the api call:

```
  getWeather$ = createEffect(() => {
return this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType(WeatherApiActions.getWeather),
  switchMap((action: { type: string, cityId: number }) => this.weatherService.getWeather(action.cityId)),
  map((weather: IWeather) => WeatherApiActions.getWeatherSuccess({ weather }))
)
})
```

As you can see I am writing the type here in the effect (the "cityId"). But there is a huge drawback here and this use makes the effect tightly coupled with the action. It means that if you decided to change the "getWeather" action you will also need to change the corresponding effect. So I figure there is a better way of handling this and my question is - How to do this without breaking the loose coupling

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `createAction` to define your actions, you can create a strongly typed action:

```
export class GetWeather implements Action {
  readonly type = '[Weather] Get Weather';
  constructor(public cityId: number) {}
}
```

Then in your effect:

```
  getWeather$ = createEffect(() => {
return this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType(GetWeather.type),
  switchMap((action: GetWeather => this.weatherService.getWeather(action.cityId)),
  map((weather: IWeather) => WeatherApiActions.getWeatherSuccess({ weather }))
)
})
```

Comment: Isn't there a way to do this with the "createAction" function? If what you are suggesting is the only solution then it means that I need to export all the types for the "classes" and also to export the consts that I created with the "createAction" function. It is a mess and one can find himself exporting half of the actions as classes and half of the actions in types.

Answer (score 0):

In the latest versions of NgRx you can pass an `ActionCreator` to `ofType`, and then `action` should be correctly typed:

```
  getWeather$ = createEffect(() => {
    return this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(getWeather),
      switchMap((action) =>
        this.weatherService.getWeather(action.cityId)
      ),
      map((weather) =>
        WeatherApiActions.getWeatherSuccess({ weather })
      )
    );
  });
```